# How to split a single line into multiple lines in Excel (like an SQL unpivot operation)?

Tags: excel, unpivot

I have an Excel sheet with many data in it. I simplified the problem with only several rows of data. Take a look at below snapshot:

[image]

Right now my data looks like the upper rows and what I want is the arrow pointed part. What's the easiest way to complete this? Thanks.

Comment: Google "excel unpivot data".  Found "http://excel.solutions/2014/03/unpivot-excel-data/" and "http://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/", and many of other examples.  While these show how to unpivot one dimension, and you have two dimensions to unpivot, it may get you pointed down the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify how many rows and columns of data are there in your file.

If the no of columns are not too many then simply put filter on blank rows and then copy paste the data. So for example. Column A, B, C are Ok. Now put a filter on column D and exclude all blanks. Now copy and paste the Column A, D and E below the last record of Columns A,B and c. Now you can delete the data in Columns D and E. Repeat the same process then for columns F and G and similarly for further column data.